# Dynamically add multiple rows in datagridview in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, excel, datagridview

Im reading cell values from excel sheet and add it in datagridview.
I followed below code but it add only one row and it is the last row in excel sheet. I have four rows in excel sheet so datagridview also should have four rows.

```
 For x = 9 To xlWorkSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
            For j = 0 To LogCalcEnter.ColumnCount - 1
                If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(xlWorkSheet.Cells(1 + x, j + 1).Value) Then
                    LogCalcEnter.Rows.Add()
                    LogCalcEnter.Item(j, 0).Value = xlWorkSheet.Cells(1 + x, j + 1).value
                End If
            Next
        Next
```

LogCalcEnter is name of the Datagridview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You add a new row for every **column** that you are looping over. The code below creates a new **row** for each row you loop over. I changed `LogCalcEnter.Item(j, 0)` to `LogCalcEnter.Item(j, rowIndex)` so that you're filling out the row information too. Note: I haven't actually run it, you may have issues with the indices you are using in this. You say you have 4 rows in the spreadsheet but you started with x = 9. Also the +1's in `xlWorkSheet.Cells(1 + x, j + 1).Value)` push the row count over the amount in UsedRange.

```
    For x = 1 To xlWorkSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        Dim rowIndex = LogCalcEnter.Rows.Add()
        Dim hasValue = False
        For j = 0 To LogCalcEnter.ColumnCount - 1
            If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(xlWorkSheet.Cells(1 + x, j + 1).Value) Then
                hasValue = True
                LogCalcEnter.Item(j, rowIndex).Value = xlWorkSheet.Cells(1 + x, j + 1).value
            End If
        Next
        If Not hasValue Then LogCalEnter.Rows.RemoveAt(rowIndex)
    Next
```

Comment: Yes it works. Actually the data i want to import from excel is started from 10th row. up to 14th row i have data after that empty cells only. But Used Range returns 50 rows. So empty rows getting added in datagridview. That why i put Rows.Add() after IsNullorEmpty If loop check.

Comment: I've modified the code so that empty rows aren't added.